# How Do I Update The Shopware 6 Sales Channel Table When It Refuses To Update Via The Admin API

Tags: vue.js, shopware6, shopware6-api

I have been trying to update the 'payment_method_ids' column of the 'sales_channel' table of Shopware 6 via the Vue JS administration API without it working or even generating any error. But, when I update the 'payment_method_id' column of the same 'sales_channel' table, it works just fine.

Below is my code:

```js
const { Component} = Shopware;
import template from './store-settings-page.html.twig';
Component.register('store-settings-page', {
   template,
   inject: [
    'repositoryFactory'
    ],

   metaInfo() {
      return {
          title: this.$createTitle()
      };
    },

  data() {
    return {
        salesChannelId: '73049sdus783993hdjnncsfm',
        paymentMethodId: 'f6dd50230aa145adb6b73801d4bcf31b',
        paymentMethodIds: ["6f4bbcbcdcfc4e449ee4c4904dc797e9", "979cad06654c475bb7bbb997f7c81774", "ba893622d71b4d25adde336862367297", "f6dd50230aa145adb6b73801d4bcf31b"],
    }
   },
   computed: {
    salesChannelRepository() {
        return this.repositoryFactory.create('sales_channel');
    },
   },
   methods: {
    updatePaymentMethodId(){
        this.salesChannelRepository
            .get(this.salesChannelId, Shopware.Context.api)
            .then((update) => {
                update.paymentMethodId = this.paymentMethodId;
                this.salesChannelRepository.save(update, Shopware.Context.api);
            });  
    },
    updatePaymentMethodIds(){
        this.salesChannelRepository
            .get(this.salesChannelId, Shopware.Context.api)
            .then((update) => {
                update.paymentMethodIds = this.paymentMethodIds;
                this.salesChannelRepository.save(update, Shopware.Context.api);
            });    
    },
   },
   created() {
    this.updatePaymentMethodIds();
   }
})
```

Comment: What do you see in your network tab? You probably have a response of some sort.

Comment: I've updated your snippet to make it far more readable. Please make an effort next time.

Comment: @kissu I see a 'POST' request with URL http://localhost/api/search/sales-channel  for "**updatePaymentMethodIds**" function and on the "**updatePaymentMethodId**" function it shows a PATCH request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paymentMethodIds` is a `ManyToManyIdField` of the `SalesChannelDefinition`. These fields represent a special case. The content for these fields is computed server-side by the corresponding `EntityIndexer` instance. So when you assign a payment method to the sales channel, the column of the `paymentMethodIds` should automatically be updated.

If you want to add payment methods programmatically, you should use the actual association field instead:

```js
// create a new payment method entity
const paymentMethod = this.repositoryFactory.create('payment_method')
    .create(Shopware.Context.api, this.paymentMethodId);
// or fetch an existing one
// const paymentMethod = await this.repositoryFactory.create('payment_method')
//     .get(this.paymentMethodId, Shopware.Context.api);

const criteria = new Criteria(1, 1);
criteria.addAssociation('paymentMethods');

this.salesChannelRepository
    .get(this.salesChannelId, Shopware.Context.api, criteria)
    .then((update) => {
        update.paymentMethods.add(paymentMethod);
        this.salesChannelRepository.save(update, Shopware.Context.api);
    });
```